# CiviCRM Individual Contact Inherits fields from Organisation

Tags: permissions, relationships, fields, coding-standards

I am wondering is it possible to Copy fields  from a Organisation Contact  depending on relationship?

For e.g. If there is a relationship between Contact A and Contact B can Contact B inherit fields from Contact A.

Contact A - Organisation
Contact B - Individual

E.g. If there is a relationship, Contact B Field "Address" will be inherited from Contact A.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviCRM offers the option of having a Shared Address but there is no way out of the box to trigger that automatically (that I am aware of).

Depending on how you are adding Contacts if you were using Drupal Webforms or WordPress Caldera forms it would be possible to do this (not certain with WP but def. with Drupal)

Comment: Thanks for your message, is there a way for employees of a company to inherit the relationship of the employer for e.g. Account Manager for "Company Name" all the employees inherit that relationship?

Comment: sorry i don't understand the above. why would all the employees be 'account manager'?